# $_POST not working on mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, database

I have got a problem when I try to pass two variables to mysql database to select all the name and surname from a table, but only for the given username and password (the variables I am passing).
If I don't use any $_POST the program correctly fetch ALL the name and surname I have got in my Contacts table. But that's not what I need. I actually need to get back names and surnames only for the given username and password.

Here is my code

```
    public class ApiConnector {  
public JSONArray GetAllCustomers(User user){
String url = "http://giacomoci.co.uk/FetchallDataList.php";
ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));
HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

JSONArray jsonArray = null;

try {


    //DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));


    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(post);

    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

    if(httpEntity != null){

        try {

            String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            Log.e("Entity Response : ", entityResponse);

            jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return jsonArray;
    }}
```

and PHP file

```
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT name, surname FROM Contacts
      WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
    $user[] = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement)){
    $user[] = $row;}
    echo json_encode($user);
    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: You have to execute the prepared statement. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php I think the issue isn't that it is empty but is that you aren't executing. Are you outputting values and they are empty or no JSON returned?

Comment: I was making some test. Actually if don't pass these variables at all and simply use the statement "SELECT name, surname FROM Contacts"  everything is working properly. I mean i get back the whole list of contacts (So i don't filter by username and password). Is when I try to pass those variables that I have got problem and the Json I get back is empty. I tried manually to set username and password inside the php in the statement and also works fine. that's why I'm pretty sure that is all about $username and $password that I'm passing

Comment: Without executing your query I don't see how you'd get results. If you output the POST array on the PHP page is it empty?

Comment: the statement is executed in the while loop. How can i output the POST at run time so I'll make sure that is empty or not? cause I debugged the java code and apparently datatosand is correctly set. Thanks

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` should give you output. The fetch which enters beings your while loop needs an execute. Did you just add `i` to previous `mysql_` functions? Looks like that `fetch` function doesn't exist, http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=mysqli_fetch_assoc&lang=en.

Comment: but I don't understand why everything is working if i just use "SELECT name, surname FROM Contacts" without using username and password. I retrieve all the contact list for all usernames and password.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php